# How to have a tri-state 'boolean' in c++

Tags: c++, boolean

What is the best way to have three value Boolean variable in c++?

I would like to have fields set to `true`, `false` or not set at all in my array.

If I declare them this way:

```
t[0] = true;
t[1] = false;
t[2] = NULL;
```

When I test the condition I get:

`t[2]` is `false`

Comment: Create an enum holding your three values

Comment: [Almost there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-valued_logic).. Implementing the logical operators for {0,1,Z,X} in an efficient class would be useful. Z maps to 'indeterminate' in the boost triclass and is also noted as 'both'. 'X' or don't care is the opposite of indeterminate. This is for logical cases where a value is of no consequence; It doesn't matter. [DB implementing 4value logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183540/is-there-any-implementation-of-4-valued-logic-database)

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at boost.tribool: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/tribool.html

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
t[0] = true;
t[1] = false;
t[2] = -1;
```

Or if you only need 3 states but perhaps would like more at some point, an `enum` is great:

```
enum STATES
{
    NULL_STATE = -1,    // you can manually specify -1 to give it a special case value
    FALSE,              // will be equal to 0
    TRUE                // will be equal to 1
};
```

No matter what though, `0/false` is the only thing that returns `false` in an `if()` statement. `-1` and `true` both return `true`.

You may want to use a switch like this to deal with 3+ states:

```
switch (var)    // may need to cast: (int)var
{
case 1:
case 0:
case -1:
};
```

Alternatively if you want to stick to an if statement block, you could do something like this:

```
if (var == -1)    // or (var == NULL_STATE)
{}
else if (var)     // true condition
{}
else              // false
{}
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using `std::experimental::optional<bool>` (if your C++ standard library has it), or `boost::optional<bool>` (www.boost.org).

I believe `std::optional` is a candidate for C++17 so if you adopt one of the above then your refactoring effort to C++17 ought to be minimal.

If you don't like using things that are not (yet?) in the "proper" C++ standard library, then consider

1. Something based around `std::unique_ptr<bool>`
2. A `std::pair<bool, bool>`
3. A good old-fashioned `enum` with 3 values.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::optional` for this:

```
std::optional<bool> t[3];

t[0] = true;
t[1] = false;
t[2] = std::nullopt;

for (auto const& i : t)
  if (i.has_value()) std::cout << i.value() << '\n';
```

output:

```
1
0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use boost::optional

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

```
boost::optional<bool> myBooleanVariable;
```

I agree that tribool can be better if you don't need the uninitialised values to be NULL. Where comparing optional and tribool, the documentation says:

> First, it is functionally similar to a tristate boolean (false, maybe, true) —such as boost::tribool— except that in a tristate boolean, the maybe state represents a valid value, unlike the corresponding state of an uninitialized optional. It should be carefully considered if an optional instead of a tribool is really needed.

Source: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/a_note_about_optional_bool_.html

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to have three value Boolean variable in c++?

Boolean values by definition only have 2 possible states - True or False.
If you want to have another state for 'invalid' or 'not set' then you need to encapsulate the bool variable in some other data-types.

The right solution depends on what you want to do with that variable.
For simple comparisons (if-else and switch) scoped enums (c++11) should be preferred.

```
enum class tristate{true,false,undefined=0};
```

They are simple, easy to use and understand and offer type safety over plane old enums. As they are type-safe you can not accidentally compare it with different types of enums or numeral types, But it also means you can not use bitfiddling and integer-tricks either.
Unless a different type is specified an enum class is a numerical type which gets initialized to '0'. that means by assigning the value '0' to one of the enum-values you can make that the default state.

```
tristatet[7];
t[1] = tristate::true;
t[2] = tristate::false;
t[3] = tristate::undefined;
t[4] = false; //error
t[5] = 0; //error
t[6] = null; //error

t[0] == true; //error
t[0] == tristate::true; // false
t[0] == tristate::undefined; // true
```

Of course you can use that in a switch-statement:

```
switch(t[2]) {
  case tristate::true:
       foo(); break;
  case tristate::false:
       bar(); break; //t[2] was set to tristate::false
  case tristate::undefined :
       doNothing(); break; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also believe an enum declaration is the cleaner and simplest solution.

A small note on the size of the new type: enums are usually (depending of course on the compiler) backed by integers, so you are allocating something like 32 or 64 bits to actually use 2 bits.

In newer C++ (C++11), you can specify the underlying type of the enum (to an existing integral type). For example:

```cpp
enum tribool: uint8_t {False = 0, True = 1, Unknown = 2};
...
enum tribool f = tribool::False;
```