# Is there any implementation of 4-valued logic database?

Tags: database, logic, rdbms

All of the current implementation of DBMS support three-valued logic that has:

- True
- False
- Unknown, this is interpreted as NULL

The three-value logic is also part of RM/v1 (Relational Model v1).

The four-valued logic that is related to Belnap's relevance logic, is also mentioned in RM/v2. It has:

- True
- False
- Unknown
- Inconsistent

I was looking for any DBMS or any other implementation supporting four-valued logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current crop of SQL DBMSs don't implement 3VL correctly either.

Comment: I’m amazed that this has been in academia for more than 20 years and I can’t find any implementation of it.

Comment: I agree. But I also can't find a definition of a 4-valued logic that would actually be useful in a database system. There are some papers which claim that, but if you have some DB experience and look at it, then you see that it's not really the case. So I would say that this is a decades old hoax.